# Haskell: Lists, Arrays, Vectors, Sequences

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and read a couple of articles regarding performance differences of Haskell lists and (insert your language)'s arrays.

Being a learner I obviously just use lists without even thinking about performance difference.
I recently started investigating and found numerous data structure libraries available in Haskell.

Can someone please explain the difference between Lists, Arrays, Vectors, Sequences without going very deep in computer science theory of data structures?

Also, are there  some common patterns where you would use one data structure instead of another?

Are there any other forms of data structures that I am missing and might be useful?

Comment: Have a look at this answer about lists vs arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196667/haskell-arrays-vs-lists
Vectors have mostly the same performance as arrays, but a larger API.

Comment: Would be nice to see Data.Map discussed here too. This seems like a useful data structure especially for multi-dimensional data.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

### Lists Rock

By far the most friendly data structure for sequential data in Haskell is the List

```
 data [a] = a:[a] | []
```

Lists give you ϴ (1) cons and pattern matching. The standard library, and for that matter the prelude, is full of useful list functions that should litter your code (`foldr`, `map`, `filter`). Lists are *persistent*, aka purely functional, which is very nice. Haskell lists aren't really "lists" because they are coinductive (other languages call these streams) so things like

```
ones :: [Integer]
ones = 1:ones

twos = map (+1) ones

tenTwos = take 10 twos
```

Work wonderfully. Infinite data structures rock.

Lists in Haskell provide an interface much like iterators in imperative languages (because of laziness). So, it makes sense that they are widely used.

## On the other hand

The first problem with lists is that to index into them `(!!)` takes ϴ (k) time, which is annoying. Also, appends can be slow `++`, but Haskell's lazy evaluation model means that these can be treated as fully amortized if they happen at all.

The second problem with lists is that they have poor data locality. Real processors incur high constants when objects in memory are not laid out next to each other. So, in C++ `std::vector` has faster "snoc" (putting objects at the end) than any pure linked list data structure I know of, although this is not a persistent data structure so less friendly than Haskell's lists.

The third problem with lists is that they have poor space efficiency. Bunches of extra pointers push up your storage (by a constant factor).

### Sequences Are Functional

`Data.Sequence` is internally based on [finger trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) (I know, you don't want to know this) which means that they have some nice properties

1. Purely functional. `Data.Sequence` is a fully persistent data structure.
2. Darn fast access to the beginning and end of the tree. ϴ (1) (amortized) to get the first or last element, or to append trees. At the thing lists are fastest at, `Data.Sequence` is at most a constant slower.
3. ϴ (log n) access to the middle of the sequence. This includes inserting values to make new sequences
4. High-quality API

On the other hand, `Data.Sequence` doesn't do much for the data locality problem, and only works for finite collections (it is less lazy than lists)

### Arrays are not for the faint of heart

Arrays are one of the most important data structures in CS, but they don't fit very well with the lazy pure functional world. Arrays provide ϴ (1) access to the middle of the collection and exceptionally good data locality/constant factors. But, since they don't fit very well into Haskell, they are a pain to use. There are actually a multitude of different array types in the current standard library. These include fully persistent arrays, mutable arrays for the IO monad, mutable arrays for the ST monad, and un-boxed versions of the above. For more check out [the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays)

### Vector is a "better" Array

The `Data.Vector` package provides all of the array goodness, in a higher level and cleaner API. Unless you really know what you are doing, you should use these if you need array-like performance. Of course, some caveats still apply – mutable array-like data structures just don't play nice in pure lazy languages. Still, sometimes you want that O (1) performance, and `Data.Vector` gives it to you in a usable package.

### You have other options

If you just want lists with the ability to efficiently insert at the end, you can use a [difference list](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list). The best example of lists screwing up performance tends to come from `[Char]` which the prelude has aliased as `String`. `Char` lists are convient, but tend to run on the order of 20 times slower than C strings, so feel free to use `Data.Text` or the very fast `Data.ByteString`. I'm sure there are other sequence oriented libraries I'm not thinking of right now.

### Conclusion

90+% of the time I need a sequential collection in Haskell lists are the right data structure. Lists are like iterators, functions that consume lists can easily be used with any of these other data structures using the `toList` functions they come with. In a better world the prelude would be fully parametric as to what container type it uses, but currently `[]` litters the standard library. So, using lists (almost) everywhere is definitely okay.
You can get fully parametric versions of most of the list functions (and are noble to use them)

```
Prelude.map                --->  Prelude.fmap (works for every Functor)
Prelude.foldr/foldl/etc    --->  Data.Foldable.foldr/foldl/etc
Prelude.sequence           --->  Data.Traversable.sequence
etc
```

In fact, `Data.Traversable` defines an API that is more or less universal across anything "list like".

Still, although you can be good and write only fully parametric code, most of us are not and use lists all over the place. If you are learning, I strongly suggest you do too.

---

Based on comments I realize I never explained when to use `Data.Vector` vs `Data.Sequence`. Arrays and Vectors provide extremely fast indexing and slicing operations but are fundamentally transient (imperative) data structures. Pure functional data structures like `Data.Sequence` and `[]` let efficiently produce *new* values from old values as if you had modified the old values.

```
newList oldList = 7 : drop 5 oldList
```

Doesn't modify the old list, and it doesn't have to copy it. So even if `oldList` is incredibly long, this "modification" will be very fast. Similarly

```
newSequence newValue oldSequence = Sequence.update 3000 newValue oldSequence
```

Will produce a new sequence with a `newValue` for in the place of its 3000 elements. Again, it doesn't destroy the old sequence, it just creates a new one. But, it does this very efficiently, taking O (log (min (k, k-n) where n is the length of the sequence, and k is the index you modify.

You can't easily do this with `Vectors` and `Arrays`. They can be *modified* but that is a real imperative modification, and so can't be done in regular Haskell code. That means operations in the `Vector` package that make modifications like `snoc` and `cons` have to copy the entire vector so takes `O(n)` time. The only exception to this is that you can use the mutable version (`Vector.Mutable`) inside the `ST` monad (or `IO`) and do all your modifications just like you would in an imperative language. When you are done, you "freeze" your vector to turn it into the immutable structure you want to use with pure code.

My feeling is that you should default to using `Data.Sequence` if a list is not appropriate. Use `Data.Vector` only if your usage pattern doesn't involve making many modifications, or if you need extremely high performance within the ST/IO monads.

If all this talk of the `ST` monad is leaving you confused: all the more reason to stick to pure fast and beautiful `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: One insight I've heard is that lists are basically as much a control structure as a data structure in Haskell. And this makes sense: where you would use a C-style for loop in a different language, you would use a `[1..]` list in Haskell. Lists can also be used for fun things like backtracking. Thinking about them as control structures (sort of) really helped make sense of how they're used.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis nice, "as much a control structure as a data structure" captures something fundamental about how lists are used.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. Very nice answer. :)

Comment: Excellent answer. My only complaint is that "Sequences are functional" is underselling them a bit. Sequences are functional awesomesauce. One other bonus to them is fast joining and splitting (log n).

Comment: @DanBurton Fair. I did probably undersell `Data.Sequence`.  Finger trees are one of the most awesome inventions in the history of computing (Guibas should probably get a Turing award someday) and `Data.Sequence` is an excellent implementation and has a very useable API.

Comment: @PhilipJF, what would be the advantages and disadvantages of using Data.Sequence over Data.Vector? Vectors too have list-like control structure, and iterators, but seem to have data locality advantages of arrays. I have used vectors and lists in my code, but haven't used sequence. I must be missing out on something sequence offers that list and vectors can't.

Comment: "UseData.Vector only if your usage pattern doesn't involve making many modifications, or if you need extremely high performance within the ST/IO monads.." Interesting wording, because if you *are* making many modifications (like repeatedly (100k times) evolving 100k elements ) , then you *do* need ST/IO Vector to get acceptable performance,

Comment: The concerns about (pure) vectors and copying are partially alleviated by stream fusion, e.g. this: `import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU; main = print (VU.cons 'a' (VU.replicate 100 'b'))` compiles to a single allocation of 404 bytes (101 chars) in Core: http://hpaste.org/65015

Comment: @TikhonJelvis:  That's because the list is a monad.

Comment: How well does `Data.IntMap` fare compared to these other structures? To me it sounds like `IntMap` is meant for sparse keys primarily. Is that correct?

Comment: Either `Data.Vector` seems to be no more, or [I suck at searching](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Data.Vector). Which one is the case?

Comment: @JanDvorak [vector is on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) and [part of the platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/platform/lib/vector-0.10.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html).  It isn't in base so you have to use [`+vector` in hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Bvector+Data.Vector) which is annoying.  You can also [use hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=vector) which searches beyond base.

Comment: I believe concatenating Data.Sequence is O(log n), not O(1).

Comment: Please, tell me where I can find more information related to `ϴ` symbol presented in this answer, specially related to computer science of course.

Comment: @FtheBuilder: That's Big O Notation. You can read about it on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation or just from searching around here.

Comment: As of newer GHC versions, `Prelude.map` and similar functions are already generalised to use more general type signatures.

Comment: Is this answer up to date in 2021?

Comment: To me, it seems like convention is going towards "use `Vector` if you are ever going to allocate space".

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. However, I also suggest: If you find yourself writing `list !! n` only once: Use a `Vector` (unboxed if possible).