# creating custom instance of UArray

Tags: arrays, haskell, unboxing

Suppose I have a simple data type like:

```
data Cell = Open | Blocked
```

and I'd like to use a `UArray Int Cell`. Is there an easy way to do this? Can I somehow reuse the definition for `UArray Int Bool`?

Comment: Assuming you want to use an `Unbox` vector of `Cell`s, you'd need instances of `Unbox`, `Data.Mutable.MVector`, and `Data.Vector.Vector`, plus two type family instances. This can be result a bit of nasty boilerplate, but it can be copied from the `Unbox` code for `Bool`. An alternative would be to make a `Storable` instance for `Cell` and use `Storable` vector. I'm not aware of any efficiency difference between the two vector types.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613203/925978) explains why Vectors are better than Arrays, so I'm going to give you the answer for unboxed vectors.

I did try deriving an `MArray` and `IArray` instance for `Cell` based on the `Bool` instances, but the `Bool` instances are quite complicated; it would be at least as ugly as manually deriving an `Unbox` instance for vectors. Unlike vectors, you also can't just derive `Storable` and use `Storable` arrays: you still need the `Marray` and `IArray` instances. There doesn't appear to be a nice TH solution yet, so you're better off using vectors for those reasons as well.

There are several ways to do this, some more painful than others.

1. [vector-th-unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html)

   Pros: Straightforward, much shorter than manually deriving `Unbox` instances

   Cons: Requires `-XTemplateHaskell`

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

   import Data.Vector.Unboxed
   import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving
   import qualified Data.Vector.Generic
   import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable

   data Cell = Open | Blocked deriving (Show)

   derivingUnbox "Cell"
       [t| Cell -> Bool |]
       [| \ x -> case x of
           Open -> True
           Blocked -> False |]
       [| \ x -> case x of
           True -> Open
           False -> Blocked |]

   main = print $ show $ singleton Open
   ```
2. Write your own `Unbox`, `M.MVector`, and `V.Vector` instances, plus two data instances

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

   import qualified Data.Vector.Generic            as V
   import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable    as M
   import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed            as U
   import Control.Monad

   data Cell = Open | Blocked deriving (Show)

   data instance U.MVector s Cell = MV_Cell (U.MVector s Cell)
   data instance U.Vector Cell = V_Cell (U.Vector Cell)

   instance U.Unbox Cell

   {- purloined and tweaked from code in `vector` 
      package that defines types as unboxed -}
   instance M.MVector U.MVector Cell where
     {-# INLINE basicLength #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeSlice #-}
     {-# INLINE basicOverlaps #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeNew #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeReplicate #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeRead #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeWrite #-}
     {-# INLINE basicClear #-}
     {-# INLINE basicSet #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeCopy #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeGrow #-}

     basicLength (MV_Cell v) = M.basicLength v
     basicUnsafeSlice i n (MV_Cell v) = MV_Cell $ M.basicUnsafeSlice i n v
     basicOverlaps (MV_Cell v1) (MV_Cell v2) = M.basicOverlaps v1 v2
     basicUnsafeNew n = MV_Cell `liftM` M.basicUnsafeNew n
     basicUnsafeReplicate n x = MV_Cell `liftM` M.basicUnsafeReplicate n x
     basicUnsafeRead (MV_Cell v) i = M.basicUnsafeRead v i
     basicUnsafeWrite (MV_Cell v) i x = M.basicUnsafeWrite v i x
     basicClear (MV_Cell v) = M.basicClear v
     basicSet (MV_Cell v) x = M.basicSet v x
     basicUnsafeCopy (MV_Cell v1) (MV_Cell v2) = M.basicUnsafeCopy v1 v2
     basicUnsafeMove (MV_Cell v1) (MV_Cell v2) = M.basicUnsafeMove v1 v2
     basicUnsafeGrow (MV_Cell v) n = MV_Cell `liftM` M.basicUnsafeGrow v n

   instance V.Vector U.Vector Cell where
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeFreeze #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeThaw #-}
     {-# INLINE basicLength #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeSlice #-}
     {-# INLINE basicUnsafeIndexM #-}
     {-# INLINE elemseq #-}

     basicUnsafeFreeze (MV_Cell v) = V_Cell `liftM` V.basicUnsafeFreeze v
     basicUnsafeThaw (V_Cell v) = MV_Cell `liftM` V.basicUnsafeThaw v
     basicLength (V_Cell v) = V.basicLength v
     basicUnsafeSlice i n (V_Cell v) = V_Cell $ V.basicUnsafeSlice i n v
     basicUnsafeIndexM (V_Cell v) i = V.basicUnsafeIndexM v i
     basicUnsafeCopy (MV_Cell mv) (V_Cell v) = V.basicUnsafeCopy mv v
     elemseq _ = seq

   main = print $ show $ U.singleton Open
   ```

   Wasn't that fun?
3. Create a `Storable` instance and use `Data.Vector.Storable` instead.

   Pros: No TH, and relatively simple instance

   Cons: The instance is less obvious than the TH definition. Also, whenever you ask a SO question about `Storable` vectors, someone will inevitably ask why you aren't using `Unboxed` vectors, though no one seems to know why `Unboxed` vectors are better.

   For a data:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

   import Control.Monad
   import Data.Vector.Storable
   import Foreign.Storable

   import GHC.Ptr
   import GHC.Int

   -- defined in HsBaseConfig.h as 
   -- #define HTYPE_INT Int32
   type HTYPE_INT = Int32

   data Cell = Open | Blocked deriving (Show)

   instance Storable Cell where
    sizeOf _          = sizeOf (undefined::HTYPE_INT)
    alignment _       = alignment (undefined::HTYPE_INT)
    peekElemOff p i   = liftM (\x -> case x of 
                           (0::HTYPE_INT) -> Blocked
                           otherwise -> Open) $ peekElemOff (castPtr p) i
    pokeElemOff p i x = pokeElemOff (castPtr p) i $ case x of
       Blocked -> 0
       Open -> (1 :: HTYPE_INT)

   main = print $ show $ singleton Open
   ```

   Or for a newtype:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

   import Data.Vector.Storable as S
   import Foreign.Storable

   newtype Cell = IsOpen Bool deriving (Show)

   main = print $ show $ S.singleton (Foo True)
   ```
4. Unbox instances for `newtype`

   This doesn't directly apply to your question since you don't have a `newtype`, but I'll include it for completeness.

   Pros: No TH, no code to write, still using `Unboxed` vectors for the haters

   Cons: None?

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, 
                StandaloneDeriving, 
                MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

   import Data.Vector.Generic as V
   import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as M
   import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

   newtype Cell = IsOpen Bool deriving (Unbox, Show)
   deriving instance V.Vector U.Vector Cell
   deriving instance M.MVector U.MVector Cell

   main = print $ show $ U.singleton (IsOpen True)
   ```

   **EDIT**

   Note that this solution currently [isn't possible in GHC 7.8](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9112).