# Either in unboxed vectors

Tags: haskell, unboxing, algebraic-data-types

I want to store something like an Either type in a Data.Vector.Unboxed.Unbox vector. I assume I should create a Unbox instance for "Either a b" where a and b are Unbox (ignoring the orphan issue for now). What's the best way of doing this? Should I store it the same way as (Bool,a,b)? I'm much more concerned about speed than space.

Comment: One option is to use three vectors, one of Bools, one of a's and one of b's.  Of course, your types `a` and `b` have to some default value.

Comment: Right, this is how the Vector code handles (Bool,a,b).

Is there an easy way to get a default value for something that's an instance of Unbox?

Comment: I don't see that `Unbox` requires a default value. To make your code generic you might have to introduce your own `DefaultValue` type class to define the defaults. Or define a data structure like `data EitherVector a b = (a,b,Vector (Bool,a,b))`.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896924/creating-custom-instance-of-uarray/21897900#21897900)

Answer (score 1):

To store sum types in unboxed structures you'll need to use the product encoding of them. E.g. as a tuple of the type tag and the pair of values.

So:

```
  Unbox a, Unbox b => Either a b
-->
  Unbox (Int, a, b)
```

With appropriate default values for the "empty" slots for a and b.