# Differences between Storable and Unboxed Vectors

Tags: haskell, haskell-vector

So ... I've used unboxed vectors (from the `vector` package) preferably now without giving it much consideration. `vector-th-unbox` makes creating instances for them a breeze, so why not.

Now I ran into an instance where it is not possible for me to automatically derive those instances, a data type with phantom type parameters (as in `Vector (s :: Nat) a`, where `s` encodes the length).

This made me think about the differences between `Storable` and `Unboxed` vectors. Things I figured out on my own:

- `Unboxed` will store eg tuples as separate vectors leading to better cache locality, by not wasting bandwidth when only one of those values is needed.
- `Storable` will still be compiled to simple (and probably efficient) `readArray#`s that return unboxed values (as evident by reading core).
- `Storable` allows direct pointer access which allows interoperability with foreign code. `Unboxed` doesn't.
- [edit] `Storable` instances are actually easier to write by hand than `Unbox` (that is `Vector` and `MVector`) ones.

That alone doesn't make it evident to me why `Unboxed` even exists, there seem to be little benefit to it. Probably I am missing something there?

Comment: I swear I ranted about this somewhere, but I cannot find it anymore :( I'm not aware of any performance difference between `Unboxed` and `Storable` vectors. You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21897900/925978) helpful, as well as my comment on the OP.

Comment: Hmm ... "everyone wants unboxed without knowing why" comment seem appropriate.

Comment: Haha, it *was* in there! I suppose I'm interested in an answer to this question, since it was essentially posed in my (linked) answer as well.

Comment: `Storable` vectors are just `ForeignPtr`s, so it has all the same properties: running a finalizer, not movable by GC, etc. Furthermore, `Storable` instances should lay out arrays of the type in a way that should be recognized as an array by C (i.e. contiguous, correct alignment) - however, `Unbox` allows you to write custom instances which do whatever the hell you want! e.g. you may read every `k`th element more frequently than the rest, so you may decide to store those elements in a contiguous block, or as you mentioned, store tuples separately for fewer cache misses.

Comment: .. I think the doc states quite clearly why `Unbox` exists: "Data.Vector.Unboxed:
Unboxed vectors with an **adaptive representation** based on data type families."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cribbed from https://haskell-lang.org/library/vector

Storable and unboxed vectors both store their data in a byte array, avoiding
pointer indirection. This is more memory efficient and allows better usage of
caches. The distinction between storable and unboxed vectors is subtle:

- Storable vectors require data which is an instance of the [`Storable` type
  class](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/base-4.8.1.0/Foreign-Storable.html#t:Storable).
  This data is stored in `malloc`ed memory, which is *pinned* (the garbage
  collector can't move it around). This can lead to memory fragmentation, but
  allows the data to be shared over the C FFI.
- Unboxed vectors require data which is an instance of the [`Prim` type
  class](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/primitive-0.6.1.0/Data-Primitive-Types.html).
  This data is stored in GC-managed *unpinned* memory, which helps avoid memory
  fragmentation. However, this data cannot be shared over the C FFI.

Both the `Storable` and `Prim` typeclasses provide a way to store a value as
bytes, and to load bytes into a value. The distinction is what type of
bytearray is used.

As usual, the only true measure of performance will be benchmarking. However,
as a general guideline:

- If you don't need to pass values to a C FFI, and you have a `Prim` instance,
  use unboxed vectors.
- If you have a `Storable` instance, use a storable vector.
- Otherwise, use a boxed vector.

There are also other issues to consider, such as the fact that boxed vectors
are instances of `Functor` while storable and unboxed vectors are not.

Comment: Hmm... Didn't knew there are tutorials on the haskell-lang page. Maybe a paragraph like that should be added to the vector documentation.

Comment: Maybe send them a PR? Coming from a user who was confused about the library it's more likely to be merged in.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is memory overhead:

As per my measurements:

- `Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Int` has 64 Bytes overhead
- `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Int` has 48 Bytes overhead.

Source:

- https://github.com/nh2/blog/blob/master/posts/Haskell-Storable-Vector-overhead.md#bonus-info-storable-vs-unboxed-vectors
- https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues/250#issuecomment-808825417