# Would it be possible to derive Data.Vector.Unbox via GHC's generic deriving?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, storable, ghc-generics, derivingvia

It's possible to derive `Storable` via GHC's generic deriving mechanism: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-storable (and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-storable-plugin for performance). The only library I can find for deriving `Data.Vector.Unbox`, however, uses template Haskell: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox. It also requires the user to write a little code; it's not entirely automatic.

My question is, could a library like `deriving-storable` also exist for `Unbox`, or is this not possible due to some fundamental way in which `Unbox` differs from `Storable`? If the latter, does that mean it's also not possible to create a library that allows automatically deriving `Unbox` for any `Storable` type, as I could not find such a library.

I ask because ideally I'd like to avoid template Haskell and the manual annotations necessary for using `vector-th-unbox`.

Comment: Note that `Data.Vector.Storable` in the `vector` package itself provides vectors for any storable type which are, of course, unboxed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176678/differences-between-storable-and-unboxed-vectors for some notes on when they might be appropriate.  (I think memory fragmentation hysteria will be unwarranted in most applications.)

Comment: @K.A.Buhr If I just used `Data.Vector.Storable` in the times that link recommends `Unbox`, for convenience and to avoid TH, would that be an acceptable trade-off or would it be considered bad code?

Comment: I think most of the time `Storable` does a perfectly fine job, if only because it's easier to understand, but also because the memory layout is arguably often what you want with respect to cache locality. If for some reason it needs to be GC-controlled `Primitive` would be the next alternative. Although the vector library puts `Unboxed` prominently (even saying "Implementing unboxed vectors for new data types can be very easy.") I would argue it's not as user-friendly as the other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we had some `Generic_` class to convert between our own types and some uniform representation which happens to have an `Unbox` instance (which amounts to both `MVector` and `Vector` instances for the `Unboxed` variants):

```
class Generic_ a where
  type Rep_ (a :: Type) :: Type
  to_ :: a -> Rep_ a
  from_ :: Rep_ a -> a
```

Then we can use that to obtain generic implementations of the methods of [`MVector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html)/[`Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html):

```
-- (auxiliary definitions of CMV and uncoercemv at the end of this block)
-- vector imports (see gist at the end for a compilable sample)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM
import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.Base (MVector(..))



-- MVector

gbasicLength :: forall a s. CMV s a => UM.MVector s a -> Int
gbasicLength = basicLength @UM.MVector @(Rep_ a) @s . coerce

gbasicUnsafeSlice :: forall a s. CMV s a => Int -> Int -> UM.MVector s a -> UM.MVector s a
gbasicUnsafeSlice i j = uncoercemv . basicUnsafeSlice @UM.MVector @(Rep_ a) @s i j . coerce

-- etc.


-- idem Vector


-- This constraints holds when the UM.MVector data instance of a is
-- representationally equivalent to the data instance of its generic
-- representation (Rep_ a).
type CMV s a = (Coercible (UM.MVector s a) (UM.MVector s (Rep_ a)), MVector UM.MVector (Rep_ a))

-- Sadly coerce doesn't seem to want to solve this correctly so we use
-- unsafeCoerce as a workaround.
uncoercemv :: CMV s a => UM.MVector s (Rep_ a) -> UM.MVector s a
uncoercemv = unsafeCoerce
```

Now if we have some generic type

```
data MyType = MyCons Int Bool ()
```

We can define a generic instance with its isomorphism to a tuple

```
instance Generic_ MyType where
  type Rep_ MyType = (Int, Bool, ())
  to_ (MyCons a b c) = (a, b, c)
  from_ (a, b, c) = MyCons a b c
```

And from there, there is a totally generic recipe to get its `Unbox` instance, if you have `YourType` instead with its own `Generic_` instance, you can take this and literally replace `MyType` with `YourType`.

```
newtype instance UM.MVector s MyType
  = MVMyType { unMVMyType :: UM.MVector s (Rep_ MyType) }

instance MVector UM.MVector MyType where
  basicLength = gbasicLength
  basicUnsafeSlice = gbasicUnsafeSlice
  -- etc.

-- idem (Vector U.Vector MyType)

-- MVector U.Vector & Vector UM.MVector   =   Unbox
instance Unbox MyType
```

In theory all this boilerplate could be automated with internal language features (as opposed to TemplateHaskell or CPP). But there are various issues that get in the way in the current state of things.

First, `Generic_` is essentially `Generic` from [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). However, the uniform representation that gets derived by GHC is not in terms of tuples `(,)` but in terms of somewhat ad-hoc type constructors (`:+:`, `:*:`, `M1`, etc.), which lack `Unbox` instances.

- Such `Unbox` instances could be added to use `Generic` directly
- the [generics-eot](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-eot-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-Eot.html) has a variant of `Generic` relying on tuples that could be a direct replacement to `Generic_` here.

And second, `MVector` and `Vector` have quite a few methods. To avoid having to list them all, one might expect to leverage `DerivingVia` (or `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`), however they are not applicable because there are a couple of polymorphic monadic methods that prevent coercions (e.g., `basicUnsafeNew`). For now, the easiest way I can think of to abstract this is a CPP macro. In fact the vector package uses that technique internally, and it might be reusable somehow. I believe properly addressing those issues requires a deep redesign of the Vector/MVector architecture.

Gist (not complete, but compilable): https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/c7bdcbba548ee019bf6b3f1e388bd660

Comment: I would expect the big sticking point to be the fact that there are data families running around that need instances. But maybe I'm missing something.