# Unboxed vector of newtype hangs in basicUnsafeNew

Tags: haskell, newtype, haskell-vector

I'm trying to store a simple vector of three-dimensional points in space. To do this, I'm `newtype`-ing a custom `Point` and manually implement the `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector` and `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` instances for it.

However, for some reason, any attempt to use such a vector ends up in an infinite loop in `basicUnsafeNew`. The following program will hang:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as GM
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM
import Debug.Trace (trace)
import Linear (V3 (..))

-- ct => "coordinate type"
newtype Point ct = Point
  { coordinates :: ct
  }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

makePoint :: a -> a -> a -> Point (Linear.V3 a)
makePoint x y z = Point (V3 x y z)

newtype instance UM.MVector s (Point ct) = MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct))

newtype instance U.Vector (Point ct) = V_Point (U.Vector (Point ct))

instance (U.Unbox ct) => GM.MVector UM.MVector (Point ct) where
  {-# INLINE basicUnsafeNew #-}
  basicLength (MV_Point mv) = error "basicLength"
  basicUnsafeSlice i l (MV_Point mv) = error "basicUnsafeSlice"
  basicOverlaps (MV_Point mv) (MV_Point mv') = error "basicOverlaps"
  basicUnsafeNew l = trace "unsafe new" (MV_Point <$> GM.basicUnsafeNew l) -- <-- hangs!
  basicInitialize (MV_Point mv) = error "basicInitialize"
  basicUnsafeRead (MV_Point mv) i = error "basicUnsafeRead"
  basicUnsafeWrite (MV_Point mv) i x = error "basicUnsafeWrite"

instance (U.Unbox ct) => G.Vector U.Vector (Point ct) where
  basicUnsafeFreeze (MV_Point mv) = error "basicUnsafeFreeze"
  basicUnsafeThaw (V_Point v) = error "basicUnsafeThaw"
  basicLength (V_Point v) = error "basicLength"
  basicUnsafeSlice i l (V_Point v) = error "basicUnsafeSlice"
  basicUnsafeIndexM (V_Point v) i = error "basicUnsafeIndexM"

instance (U.Unbox ct) => U.Unbox (Point ct)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ U.length $ U.singleton $ makePoint (0.0 :: Double) 1.0 2.0
```

The code requires the `vector` and `linear` packages.

I pushed this code as MWE with `stack` support here for convenience: https://github.com/jtprobst/vectortest

Simply call `stack run` and observe the endless traces of "unsafe new".

I'm running with `stack --version` Version 2.5.1, Git revision d6ab861544918185236cf826cb2028abb266d6d5 x86_64 hpack-0.33.0

Note that all methods except `basicUnsafeNew` on the vector default to `error` instead of doing anything useful. This is just to exclude the possibility of them interfering in any way. It also hangs if I use the typical default implementations for these methods (for example as described in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21897900/1656636), point number 2).

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just unroll the newtype definition:

```
newtype instance UM.MVector s (Point ct)
     = MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct))
     = MV_Point (MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct)))
     = MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct))))
     = MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct)))))
     = MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct))))))
     = MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (MV_Point (UM.MVector s (Point ct)))))))
     = ...
```

This clearly isn't going anywhere.

You need to define it in terms of something *that is* already defined, not in terms of the type you're just right now defining yourself, to avoid the circular reference. The obvious candidate would be

```
newtype instance UM.MVector s (Point ct) = MV_Point (UM.MVector s ct)
```

Comment: Perfect answer, this fixes it. Thanks a lot!