# Get n elements from 2D Array at specified coordinates and direction

Tags: haskell

I have array of x,y coordinates and char elements. I need function to get list of n chars at specified coordinates toward direction. I wrote it in recurrent way:

```
import Data.Array

exampleArray = array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),'a'), ((1,2),'b'), ((2,1),'c'), ((2,2),'d')]
--       1   2  
--     +---+---+
--   1 | a | b |
--     +---+---+
--   2 | c | d |
--     +---+---+

f :: Array (Int, Int) Char -> Int -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> [Char]
f _ 0 _ _ = []
f arr n (x,y) (dirX, dirY) = (arr ! (y,x)) : f arr (n-1) (x+dirX,y+dirY) (dirX, dirY)

-- ac
list = f exampleArray 2 (1,1) (0,1) -- get 2 chars from array at 1,1 toward E

-- cb
list2 = f exampleArray 2 (1,2) (1,(-1)) -- get 2 chars from array at 1,2 toward NE
```

It works, but it is too slow and I am wondering how to optimize it?

Comment: You can redesign with primitives like this: `f arr n s (dx, dy) = take n . map (arr!) . iterate (\(!y, !x) -> (y + dy, x + dx)) . swap $ s`. And can you write your real simple example where your code work too slow?

Comment: I get `Illegal bang-pattern (use BangPatterns): ! y`

Comment: I cannot provide simple example, but consider searching patterns in thousands of arrays in gomoku AI. If you fix function I will provide time difference between both functions.

Comment: Use extension `BangPatterns` to avoid compilation error.

Comment: Getting best move was taking 17 seconds and with your function it takes 18.

Comment: I don't have experience with Data.Array, maybe @Paul Johnson is right. But I have experience with [repa](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.18/package/repa-3.4.1.2), it based on vector package, and I recomend it you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is slow, so your first step should be to port to the [vector package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector). Use the unboxed variant, as the default "boxed" representation allocates heap storage for each value and stores a pointer to it. There is no such thing as a 2-d vector so you will have to write code to transform your coordinate pairs into locations in a 1-d vector. If that still isn't fast enough then access using the `unsafeIndex` function and its relatives, which don't do bounds checking (but do not call up that which you [cannot put down](http://www.dagonbytes.com/thelibrary/lovecraft/thecaseofcharlesdexterward.htm)).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611904/haskell-lists-arrays-vectors-sequences).

Comment: I was looking for a way to optimize function, but if changing Array to unboxed vector help, I will accept your answer. Give me some time to do it.

Comment: I can't see anything intrinsically slow about your function, other than its use of Array, and hence lots of unboxed values. One other point is that by going to a 1-d implementation all your moves (N, NE, E etc) can be represented by a single offset, so you only need to do a single addition per step.

Comment: Currently in array I am using own type like `data Square =  Cross | Nought | Empty` so I can't just use vector, because it requires `Unbox` instance. Do you think It would be better to create / derive it or I should change all functions to work on chars?

Comment: I managed to derive Unbox instance with `vector-th-unbox` and port program to Vector.Unboxed, but it runs two times slower: https://pastebin.com/7CEWNfFP

Comment: Hard to say more without looking at the code. Are you compiling with optimisation on?

Comment: I am using only `-O2` option. If you tell me your bitbucket username I will give you access to private repository.

Comment: I made repository public: https://bitbucket.org/andrzej1_1/gomoku/src/93ac3ed553c0869c63f768562369bbebee2fb55a?at=vector.unboxed Could you check the code?

Comment: Having taken a quick look, I see that the movement through the board is still being done by tracking x and y separately. However in an nxm board held in a 1-d vector you can reduce the move in any direction to a single addition: a horizontal move is +/-1 and a vertical move is +/-m (and likewise for diagonal). You also have a lot of small functions, which is good style, but perhaps judicious use of the INLINE pragma might help. The profile you posted has a lot of Vector fusion binds in it, which suggests that the optimiser isn't able to fuse your operations into single loops for some reason.