# Random access performance on a 1D Haskell list

Tags: performance, haskell

I have a Haskell program which simulates the Ising  model with the Metropolis
algorithm. The main operation is a stencil operation that takes the sum of next
neighbors in 2D and then multiplies that with the center element. Then the
element is perhaps updated.

In C++, where I get decent performance, I use a 1D array and then linearize the
access to it with simple index arithmetics. In the past months I have picked up Haskell to broaden my horizon and also tried to implement the Ising model there. The data structure is just a list of `Bool`:

```
type Spin = Bool
type Lattice = [Spin]
```

Then I have some fixed extent:

```
extent = 30
```

And a `get` function which retrieves a particular lattice site, including periodic boundary conditions:

```
-- Wrap a coordinate for periodic boundary conditions.
wrap :: Int -> Int
wrap = flip mod $ extent

-- Converts an unbounded (x,y) index into a linearized index with periodic
-- boundary conditions.
index :: Int -> Int -> Int
index x y = wrap x + wrap y * extent

-- Retrieve a single element from the lattice, automatically performing
-- periodic boundary conditions.
get :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Spin
get l x y = l !! index x y
```

I use the same thing in C++ and there it works fine, though I know that the
`std::vector` guarantees me fast random access.

While profiling, I found that the `get` function takes up a significant amount
of computing time:

```
COST CENTRE                        MODULE                SRC                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

         get                       Main                  ising.hs:36:1-26          153     899100    8.3    0.4     9.2    1.9
          index                    Main                  ising.hs:31:1-36          154     899100    0.5    1.2     0.9    1.5
           wrap                    Main                  ising.hs:26:1-24          155          0    0.4    0.4     0.4    0.4
         neighborSum               Main                  ising.hs:(40,1)-(43,56)   133     899100    4.9   16.6    46.6   25.3
          spin                     Main                  ising.hs:(21,1)-(22,17)   135    3596400    0.5    0.4     0.5    0.4
          neighborSum.neighbors    Main                  ising.hs:43:9-56          134     899100    0.9    0.7     0.9    0.7
          neighborSum.retriever    Main                  ising.hs:42:9-40          136     899100    0.4    0.0    40.2    7.6
           neighborSum.retriever.\ Main                  ising.hs:42:32-40         137    3596400    0.2    0.0    39.8    7.6
            get                    Main                  ising.hs:36:1-26          138    3596400   33.7    1.4    39.6    7.6
             index                 Main                  ising.hs:31:1-36          139    3596400    3.1    4.7     5.9    6.1
              wrap                 Main                  ising.hs:26:1-24          141          0    2.7    1.4     2.7    1.4
```

I have read that the Haskell list is only good when one pushes/pops elements at the front, so performance is only given when one uses it as a stack.

When I “update” the lattice, I use `splitAt` and then `++` to return a new list which has the one element changed.

Is there something relatively straightforward that I can do do improve the random access performance?

---

The full code is here:

```
-- Copyright © 2017 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>

-- Ising model with the Metropolis algorithm. Random choice of lattice site for
-- a spin flip.

import qualified Data.Text
import System.Random

type Spin = Bool
type Lattice = [Spin]

-- Lattice extent is fixed to a square.
extent = 30
volume = extent * extent

temperature :: Double
temperature = 0.0

-- Converts a `Spin` into `+1` or `-1`.
spin :: Spin -> Int
spin True = 1
spin False = (-1)

-- Wrap a coordinate for periodic boundary conditions.
wrap :: Int -> Int
wrap = flip mod $ extent

-- Converts an unbounded (x,y) index into a linearized index with periodic
-- boundary conditions.
index :: Int -> Int -> Int
index x y = wrap x + wrap y * extent

-- Retrieve a single element from the lattice, automatically performing
-- periodic boundary conditions.
get :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Spin
get l x y = l !! index x y

-- Computes the sum of neighboring spings.
neighborSum :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Int
neighborSum l x y = sum $ map spin $ map retriever neighbors
    where
        retriever = \(x, y) -> get l x y
        neighbors = [(x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)]

-- Computes the energy difference at a certain lattice site if it would be
-- flipped.
energy :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Int
energy l x y = 2 * neighborSum l x y * (spin (get l x y))

-- Converts a full lattice into a textual representation.
latticeToString l = unlines lines
    where
        spinToChar :: Spin -> String
        spinToChar True = "#"
        spinToChar False = "."

        line :: String
        line = concat $ map spinToChar l

        lines :: [String]
        lines = map Data.Text.unpack $ Data.Text.chunksOf extent $ Data.Text.pack line

-- Populates a lattice given a random seed.
initLattice :: Int -> (Lattice,StdGen)
initLattice s = (l,rng)
    where
        rng = mkStdGen s

        allRandom :: Lattice
        allRandom = randoms rng

        l = take volume allRandom

-- Performs a single Metropolis update at the given lattice site.
update (l,rng) x y
    | doUpdate = (l',rng')
    | otherwise = (l,rng')
    where
        shift = energy l x y

        r :: Double
        (r,rng') = random rng

        doUpdate :: Bool
        doUpdate = (shift < 0) || (exp (- fromIntegral shift / temperature) > r)

        i = index x y
        (a,b) = splitAt i l
        l' = a ++ [not $ head b] ++ tail b

-- A full sweep through the lattice.
doSweep (l,rng) = doSweep' (l,rng) (extent * extent)

-- Implementation that does the needed number of sweeps at a random lattice
-- site.
doSweep' (l,rng) 0 = (l,rng)
doSweep' (l,rng) i = doSweep' (update (l,rng'') x y) (i - 1)
    where
        x :: Int
        (x,rng') = random rng

        y :: Int
        (y,rng'') = random rng'

-- Creates an IO action that prints the lattice to the screen.
printLattice :: (Lattice,StdGen) -> IO ()
printLattice (l,rng) = do
    putStrLn ""
    putStr $ latticeToString l

dummy :: (Lattice,StdGen) -> IO ()
dummy (l,rng) = do
    putStr "."

-- Creates a random lattice and performs five sweeps.
main = do
    let lrngs = iterate doSweep $ initLattice 2
    mapM_ dummy $ take 1000 lrngs
```

Comment: A list in Haskell is a linked list, so if you want random access in O(1), you probably want to use an array.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Oh, I did not know about that! Looking at [Data.Array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array.html), it seems to be perfect, it even allows for incremental updates. I'll update my program and then I'll report how it goes.

Comment: @MartinUeding `vector` is also handy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611904/haskell-lists-arrays-vectors-sequences

Comment: With `Data.Array` instead of `[]`, the program now needs 10 instead of 17 seconds. The array indexing now takes a lot less of the total time as well. In the C++ implementation my colleague is bound by the random number generator, though he uses Ranlux and I perhaps a linear congruental one? Still it appears more than a factor 10 slower than the C++ implementation, is that normal?

Comment: @MartinUeding did you measure the ten seconds in `-O2` without `-prof`? Or with `-prof`? Keep in mind that profiling will make your application slower (usually factor 2-3). I get 5s in your list version (`-O2`), and 12 seconds if I enable profiling. That being said, the `random` number generator is slow.

Comment: As I commented in @leftaroundabout's answer, I get ~6 seconds with lists and ~0.01 seconds with unboxed vectors.  N.B. The whole "use a noop IO to force the spine of a list"  method is suspect when it comes to benchmarking.

Comment: Sounds like it might be time for [comonads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html)!  (Maybe, I don't really know this algorithm, but it rang a bell.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use [`Data.Vector.Unboxed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html), which is basically the same as `std::vector`. It has very fast random access, however it doesn't really allow purely-functional updates<sup>†</sup>. You can still do such updates by working in the [`ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html), and indeed that's probably the solution that would give you the best performance, but it's not really Haskell-idiomatic.

Better: use a functional structure that allows both lookup and update and log(*n*)-ish time; this is typical for tree-based structures. [`IntMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-IntMap-Lazy.html#t:IntMap) should work pretty well.

I wouldn't recommend that either though. Generally, in Haskell you want to **avoid juggling any indices at all**. As you say, algorithms like Metropolis are actually based on a *stencil*. The operation on each spin shouldn't *ever need to see more than its direct neighbours*, so it's best to structure your program accordingly.

Even on a simple list, it's easy to achieve efficient access to the direct neighbours: implement

```
neighboursInList :: [a] -> [(a, (Maybe a, Maybe a))]
```

the actual algorithm is then just a `map` over these local-environments.

For the periodic case, you should actually make it something like

```
data Lattice a = Lattice
     { latticeNodes :: [a]
     , latticeLength :: Int }
   deriving (Functor)

data NodeInLattice a = NodeInLattice
     { thisNode :: a
     , xPrev, xNext, yPrev, yNext :: a }
   deriving (Functor)

neighboursInLattice :: Lattice a -> Lattice (NodeInLattice a)
```

Such an approach has many advantages:

- Impossible to make indexing mistakes.
- You don't rely on fast random-access.
- It can be well parallelised. For instance, the [repa library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.3/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Stencil.html) has stencil support built in. And all code that runs on supercomputers *must* use something like that, because accessing random elements that lie on another node in the cluster is way, *way* slower than accessing the processor's own node memory.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>To pure-functionally update a vector, you need to make a complete copy.</sub>

Comment: Using GHC  8.2.1 and `-O2`:  `time ./martin-orig >/dev/null` yields `5.744 total` while `time ./martin-vector >/dev/null` yields `0.019 total`

Answer (score 3):

With profiling turned off, your original version runs in about 5 seconds on my laptop.

Converting the code to use an immutable, unboxed vector (from `Data.Vector.Unboxed`) is a straightforward modification and reduces the run time to about 1.8 seconds.  Profiling that version shows that the time is dominated by the very slow `System.Random` generator.

Using a custom generator based on the `random-mersenne-pure64` package, I can get the run time down to about 0.32 seconds.  Using a linear congruential generator brings the time down to 0.22 seconds.

Re-profiling, the bottleneck appears to be bounds checking on vector operations, so replacing those with their "unsafe" counterparts gets the run time down to about 0.17 seconds.

At this point, converting to a mutable, unboxed vector (which is a more involved modification than before) didn't appreciably improve performance, but I didn't work very hard on optimizing it.  (I've seen other algorithms that benefited enormously from using mutable vectors.)

My final code for the LCG version follows.  I tried to keep as much of your original code as was reasonable.

The one annoying bit is the necessity of specifying the `extentBits` for the random index generation, and note that the algorithm will be most efficient if the extent is a power of two (because `randomIndex` generates indexes using the given number of `extentBits`, and it re-tries until the index is less than `extent`).

Note that I decided to print the number of `True`s in the final lattice instead of using a `dummy` call, since it's a little more reliable for benchmarking.

```
import Data.Bits ((.&.), shiftL)
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Spin = Bool
type Lattice = V.Vector Spin

-- Lattice extent is fixed to a square.
extent, extentBits, volume :: Int
extent = 30
extentBits = 5  -- no of bits s.t. 2**5 >= 30
volume = extent * extent

temperature :: Double
temperature = 0.0

-- Converts a `Spin` into `+1` or `-1`.
spin :: Spin -> Int
spin True = 1
spin False = (-1)

-- Wrap a coordinate for periodic boundary conditions.
wrap :: Int -> Int
wrap = flip mod $ extent

-- Converts an unbounded (x,y) index into a linearized index with periodic
-- boundary conditions.
index :: Int -> Int -> Int
index x y = wrap x + wrap y * extent

-- Retrieve a single element from the lattice, automatically performing
-- periodic boundary conditions.
get :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Spin
get l x y = l `V.unsafeIndex` index x y

-- Toggle the spin of an element
toggle :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Lattice
toggle l x y = l `V.unsafeUpd` [(i, not (l `V.unsafeIndex` i))] -- flip bit at index i
  where i = index x y

-- Computes the sum of neighboring spins.
neighborSum :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Int
neighborSum l x y = sum $ map spin $ map (uncurry (get l)) neighbors
    where
        neighbors = [(x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)]

-- Computes the energy difference at a certain lattice site if it would be
-- flipped.
energy :: Lattice -> Int -> Int -> Int
energy l x y = 2 * neighborSum l x y * spin (get l x y)

-- Populates a lattice given a random seed.
initLattice :: Int -> (Lattice,MyGen)
initLattice s = (l, rng')
    where
        rng = newMyGen s
        (allRandom, rng') = go [] rng volume
        go out r 0 = (out, r)
        go out r n = let (a,r') = randBool r
                     in go (a:out) r' (n-1)

        l = V.fromList allRandom

-- Performs a single Metropolis update at the given lattice site.
update :: (Lattice, MyGen) -> Int -> Int -> (Lattice, MyGen)
update (l, rng) x y
  | doUpdate = (toggle l x y, rng')
  | otherwise = (l, rng')
    where
        doUpdate = (shift < 0) || (exp (- fromIntegral shift / temperature) > r)
        shift = energy l x y
        (r, rng') = randDouble rng

-- A full sweep through the lattice.
doSweep :: (Lattice, MyGen) -> (Lattice, MyGen)
doSweep (l, rng) = iterate updateRand (l, rng) !! (extent * extent)

updateRand :: (Lattice, MyGen) -> (Lattice, MyGen)
updateRand (l, rng)
  = let (x, rng') = randIndex rng
        (y, rng'') = randIndex rng'
    in  update (l, rng'') x y

-- Creates a random lattice and performs five sweeps.
main :: IO ()
main = do let lrngs = iterate doSweep (initLattice 2)
              l = fst (lrngs !! 1000)
          print $ V.length (V.filter id l)  -- count the Trues

-- * Random number generation

data MyGen = MyGen Word32

newMyGen :: Int -> MyGen
newMyGen = MyGen . fromIntegral

-- | Get a (positive) integer with given number of bits.
randInt :: Int -> MyGen -> (Int, MyGen)
randInt bits (MyGen s) =
  let s' = 1664525 * s + 1013904223
      mask = (1 `shiftL` bits) - 1
  in  (fromIntegral (s' .&. mask), MyGen s')

-- | Random Bool value
randBool :: MyGen -> (Bool, MyGen)
randBool g = let (i, g') = randInt 1 g
             in  (if i==1 then True else False, g')

-- | Random index
randIndex :: MyGen -> (Int, MyGen)
randIndex g = let (i, g') = randInt extentBits g
              in if i >= extent then randIndex g' else (i, g')

-- | Random [0,1]
randDouble :: MyGen -> (Double, MyGen)
randDouble rng = let (ri, rng') = randInt 32 rng
                 in (fromIntegral ri / (2**32), rng')
```

If you prefer to use the MT generator, you can modify the imports and replace a few definitions as below.  Note that I didn't work too hard on testing `randInt`, so I'm not 100% sure it's 100% correct with all the bit twiddling that's going on there.

```
import Data.Bits ((.|.), shiftL, shiftR, xor)
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64

-- replace these definitions:

-- | Mersenne-Twister generator w/ pool of bits
data MyGen = MyGen PureMT !Int !Word64 !Int !Word64

newMyGen :: Int -> MyGen
newMyGen seed = MyGen (pureMT (fromIntegral seed)) 0 0 0 0

-- | Split w into bottom n bits and rest
splitBits :: Int -> Word64 -> (Word64, Word64)
splitBits n w =
  let w2 = w `shiftR` n             -- top 64-n bits
      w1 = (w2 `shiftL` n) `xor` w  -- bottom n bits
  in (w1, w2)

-- | Get a (positive) integer with given number of bits.
randInt :: Int -> MyGen -> (Int, MyGen)
randInt bits (MyGen p lft1 w1 lft2 w2)
  -- generate at least 64 bits
  | let lft = lft1 + lft2, lft < 64
  = let w1' = w1 .|. (w2 `shiftL` lft1)
        (w2', p') = randomWord64 p
    in randInt bits (MyGen p' lft w1' 64 w2')
  | bits > 64 = error "randInt has max of 64 bits"
  -- if not enough bits in first word, get needed bits from second
  | bits > lft1
  = let needed = bits - lft1
        (bts, w2') = splitBits needed w2
        out = (w1 `shiftL` needed) .|. bts
    in (fromIntegral out, MyGen p (lft2 - needed) w2' 0 0)
  -- otherwise, just take enough bits from first word
  | otherwise
  = let (out, w1') = splitBits bits w1
    in (fromIntegral out, MyGen p (lft1 - bits) w1' lft2 w2)
```