# Multiple lists haskell

Tags: list, haskell

How do you find nth elements in the matrix at a given row and column position? For example, if you have

```
type Matrice a = [[a]]

example :: Matrice Int  
example = [ [3, 5],                
        [2, 1],                
        [0, 4],                
        [6, 8] ] 

Prelude >  example 0 1
      5
Prelude >  example 2 0
      0
Prelude >  example 1 1
      2
```

I know how to work out with only given list such as

```
nth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth _ []       = Nothing
nth 1 (x : _)  = Just x
nth n (_ : xs) = nth (n - 1) xs
```

But my question is, how do you access nth element in a matrix as in the given example

Comment: Side note: there’s no such thing as a “matrice”—singular is “one matrix”, plural is “some matrices”, same as vertex/vertices, index/indices, appendix/appendices, &c.

Comment: `f ls m n  = ls!!m!!n` the matrix is given in ls, the list within the matrix is `m` and the element of the specified list is `n` ... [[a]] -> Int -> Int -> a ... If you want to do error checking in your function, do so but maybe use the `!!` operator.

Answer (score 4):

Just handle each list individually, and [!!](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) will work:

```
Prelude> example
[[3,5],[2,1],[0,4],[6,8]]
Prelude> :t example
example :: Matrice Int
Prelude> example !! 0 !! 1
5
```

But lists are probably not the right data structure for this, because indexing is O(n). Depending on your task, Data.Vector or Data.Array may be better suited. See also [Haskell: Lists, Arrays, Vectors, Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611904/haskell-lists-arrays-vectors-sequences).

Answer (score 2):

`!!` can be used for accessing an element by index, but be careful, since it's raising an exception, if the index is too large.

```
example !! 2 !! 0
```

And you've already written a function for accessing `nth` element of a list, just apply it twice:

```
nth :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> Maybe a
nth k n matrix = nth' n =<< nth' k matrix
  where
    nth' _ [] = Nothing
    nth' 0 (x: _) = Just x
    nth' n (_ : xs) = nth' (n - 1) xs
```

Or using your created `Matrice` type:

```
nth :: Matrice a -> Int -> Int -> Maybe a
nth matrix k n = nth' n =<< nth' k matrix
  where
    nth' _ [] = Nothing
    nth' 0 (x: _) = Just x
    nth' n (_ : xs) = nth' (n - 1) xs
```

Comment: But how do you adjust the function with this given type of nth? nth :: Matrix a -> Int -> Int -> a

Comment: @Asma but what are you going to receive, when your indices are too large and there is no element to return?