# Why is head-tail pattern matching so much faster than indexing?

Tags: performance, haskell, pattern-matching

I was working on a HackerRank problem today and initially wrote it with indexing and it was incredibly slow for most of the test cases because they were huge. I then decided to switch it to `head:tail` pattern matching and it just zoomed. The difference was absolutely night and day, but I can't figure out how it was such a change in efficiency. Here is the code for reference if it is at all useful

Most efficient attempt with indexing

```
count :: Eq a => Integral b => a -> [a] -> b
count e [] = 0
count e (a:xs) = (count e xs +) $ if a == e then 1 else 0

fullCheck :: String -> Bool
fullCheck a = prefixCheck 0 (0,0,0,0) a (length a) && (count 'R' a == count 'G' a) && (count 'Y' a == count 'B' a)

prefixCheck :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> String -> Int -> Bool
prefixCheck n (r',g',y',b') s l
  | n == l = True
  | otherwise =
    ((<= 1) $ abs $ r - g) && ((<= 1) $ abs $ y - b) 
    && prefixCheck (n+1) (r,g,y,b) s l
      where c = s !! n
            r = if c == 'R' then r' + 1 else r'
            g = if c == 'G' then g' + 1 else g'
            y = if c == 'Y' then y' + 1 else y'
            b = if c == 'B' then b' + 1 else b'

run :: Int -> IO ()
run 0 = putStr ""
run n = do
  a <- getLine
  print $ fullCheck a
  run $ n - 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  b <- getLine
  run $ read b
```

`head:tail` pattern matching attempt

```
count :: Eq a => Integral b => a -> [a] -> b
count e [] = 0
count e (a:xs) = (count e xs +) $ if a == e then 1 else 0

fullCheck :: String -> Bool
fullCheck a = prefixCheck (0,0,0,0) a && (count 'R' a == count 'G' a) && (count 'Y' a == count 'B' a)

prefixCheck :: (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> String -> Bool
prefixCheck (r,g,y,b) [] = r == g && y == b
prefixCheck (r',g',y',b') (h:s) = ((<= 1) $ abs $ r - g) && ((<= 1) $ abs $ y - b) 
    && prefixCheck (r,g,y,b) s
      where r = if h == 'R' then r' + 1 else r'
            g = if h == 'G' then g' + 1 else g'
            y = if h == 'Y' then y' + 1 else y'
            b = if h == 'B' then b' + 1 else b'

run :: Int -> IO ()
run 0 = putStr ""
run n = do
  a <- getLine
  print $ fullCheck a
  run $ n - 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  b <- getLine
  run $ read b
```

For reference as well, the question was

> You are given a sequence of `N` balls in 4 colors: red, green, yellow and blue. The sequence is full of colors if and only if all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - There are as many red balls as green balls.
> - There are as many yellow balls as blue balls.
> - Difference between the number of red balls and green balls in every prefix of the sequence is at most 1.
> - Difference between the number of yellow balls and blue balls in every prefix of the sequence is at most 1.
>
> Where a prefix of a string is any substring from the beginning to `m` where `m` is less than the size of the string

Comment: Haskell lists are [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), so while getting the first element of a list is a constant time operation, `xs !! n` is linear in the length of the list.

Comment: @AlexisKing Oh, so `hd:tl` is O(1) and `xs !! n` is O(n) in Haskell?

Comment: @EliSadoff Correct

Comment: @EliSadoff Yes. If you want a random access data structure, there are various array datatypes in various libraries, but the built-in list is just a standard singly linked list.

Comment: Please check out the [haskell tag info section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) for this and other FAQ

Comment: Highly relevant: [*Haskell arrays vs lists*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196667/haskell-arrays-vs-lists)

Comment: HackerRank ghc is very old and don't even have Data.List.Split, you might want to know there are some [alternatives](https://wiki.haskell.org/Online_judge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already got the answer in the comments why lists indexing performs linearly. But, if you are interested in a more Haskell style solution to [the Hackerrank problem your referring to](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sequence-full-of-colors), even head-tail pattern matching is unnecessary. A more performant solution can be done with right folds:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

solve :: String -> Bool
solve s = foldr go (\r g y b -> r == g && y == b) s 0 0 0 0
  where
  go x run r g y b
    | 1 < abs (r - g) || 1 < abs (y - b) = False
    | x == 'R' = run (r + 1) g y b
    | x == 'G' = run r (g + 1) y b
    | x == 'Y' = run r g (y + 1) b
    | x == 'B' = run r g y (b + 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- read <$> getLine
  replicateM_ n $ getLine >>= print . solve
```

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely beautiful.